# Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;

Tags: httpclient

> by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse;
>   in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' appears in
>   /system/framework/ext.jar)
>   where is the problem?

Comment: did you resolve this issue ?